# How to convert date and obtain new date with timezone in composiiton api by using @nuxtjs/dayjs?

Tags: vue.js, date, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, dayjs

I use @nuxtjs/dayjs in my nuxt-composiiton api project . I need to convert my date and i neeed to obtain new date with timezone

**2022-04-11T15:13:00.000Z  ---->  2022-04-11T15:13:00+03:00**

```
  const { $dayjs } = useContext();
  const date='2022-04-11T15:13:00.000Z'

  dayjs usage in composition api => $dayjs(date).format('') .....
```

Comment: This is a working solution? Feel free to mark it as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format

`console.log(' $dayjs ', $dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z'));`